# React+based on prop value i need to initiate a function which is already present in child component

Tags: reactjs

i have a doubt. am having both parent and Child component

in child component i do have one openModal function

```
openModal() {
    this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: true
    });
```

and from parent am passing one prop called 'callfunction' its value is true

so my doubt is whenever am coming from another component who do have callfunction as prop and value is true i need to call openModal() like this.openModal().
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

To do something when the component is mounted you can use the `componentDidMount` hook. This will invoke every time your component is mounted. Use it like this in your class component:

```
componentDidMount(){
  if(this.props.callfunction){
    this.openModal();
  }
}
```